# why do my constraint not work properly in swift/storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I'm using `player-swift` (that one: https://github.com/piemonte/Player ) to display video content in my app. I created a `UIViewController`, added there a `view` and assigned class to it called `PlayerView`. So far so good.

In my code I initiated it as follows:

```
self.videoPlayer = Player()
self.videoPlayer.delegate = self
self.videoPlayer.view.frame = myVideo.bounds

self.addChildViewController(self.videoPlayer)
myVideo.addSubview(self.videoPlayer.view)
self.videoPlayer.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
  let tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTapGestureRecognizer(_:)))
   tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
   self.videoPlayer.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

self.videoPlayer.fillMode = "AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill"

self.videoPlayer.setUrl(url)

self.videoPlayer.playFromBeginning()
self.videoPlayer.playbackLoops = true
```

now, since the video I'm playing is in format 480x640 (portrait mode), I thought about assigning the following constraints:

[image]

[image]

and now, when I open it on iphone 6s plus, I see:

[image]

so - since I put the trailing space to 0 - why there's still this white stripe on the right side of the screen?

On the other hand, on iphone 4s, the video is cropped:

[image]

and on iphone 6 it is fine:

[image]

what kind of constraints should I apply so that it looks on every device the same as on iphone 6? I just want it to be stretched horizontally and then the vertical length should adjust to it automatically (so that aspect ratio 480x640 is kept)

==============================================

Guys, as I wrote in the comment section below - when I removed the player and left normal view with the same constraints instead - everything worked, so it must be a player itself fault... Can you help me with distinguishing what might be wrong there?

==============================================

In my `Storyboard` I set up the color of `playerView` to light grey. I ran the simulator again and I saw:

[image]

that means there's some other layer that stores the player view itself. I went through the code of the plugin and found this:

```
public override func loadView() {
    self.playerView = PlayerView(frame: CGRectZero)
    self.playerView.fillMode = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
    self.playerView.playerLayer.hidden = true
    self.view = self.playerView
}
```

here https://github.com/piemonte/Player/blob/master/Sources/Player.swift

so I assume I need to set up somehow the constraints on: `self.playerView.playerView`. But how can I do it?

Comment: where are you calling your code? viewDidLoad?

Comment: yes, view did load, I thought maybe I should somehow set up the constraints from the code instead of story board, but still... it should be fine (in my opinion) if I set it up on the storyboard itself...

Comment: the views have not set their sizes yet in viewDidLoad. Try calling that from viewDidAppear and see if it behaves differently

Comment: @BJHStudios hmm I moved the code of the player to viewDidAppear, but now I don't see the player itself, only white panel... seems like it didn't load at a time :|

Comment: I think, or rather I am sure, that it's this plugin fault - when I removed the player from the view and added a normal `view` instead (with the same constraints) - everything works now... So now I just need some help with distinguishing what's wrong with this player and how could it be fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

the constraint to the side margins must be -20 so the video can appear full screen, 0 leaves the extra space, you can see this if you drag the view to the edge of the margin, i would recommend to ctrl drag to the main view and asign equal width to his superview

Comment: @LuizPerez I just added some more information to my main question, can you take a look at it and tell me whether it might be correct or not and how should I proceed?

Comment: Ok, let me get this straight, you are adding the player view to the main view right ? you can set the width from the storyboard, just ctrl+drag from the player view to the main view and select equal width, now if the player is in a child view and the player itself is another view means that you have 3 layers right ? (mainView, childView and playerView), tell me if this is correct

Comment: so this is how it looks: http://imgur.com/IFSI1VS so seems like I have 2 layers, I don't know how to reach the third one (the exact one where player itself is stored)...

Comment: The layer I want to set up the constraints is set up here (or at least I hope it's the one): `myVideo.addSubview(self.videoPlayer.view)` so how can I set the constraints of that particular view from the code, since I don't have access to it from story board?

Comment: ok i think i got it, on the view controller add another view, set his constraints of the size you want the video (you can set equal width, vertical spacing and height), lets name it videoContainerView, then on the code, change modify it with this line  self.player.view.frame = self.videoContainerView.bounds    , then add videoContainerView.addChildViewController(self.player) and then videoContainerView.addSubview(self.player.view), this will add the player view nested inside the view you created and will set the same size, try it and tell me if works

Comment: hm currently I'm getting this error http://imgur.com/h75OeES I did what you suggested, the `videoContainerView` is an iboutlet: `@IBOutlet weak var videoContainerView: UIView!`